# Taxonomy terms and vocabulary in form selection

Tags: 8, forms, taxonomy-terms

I 'm trying to insert vocabulary terms in my form

[image]

Only one term appears, but there are more of it.

Here is my code in .module file

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */

function bulk_taxonomy_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $vocabularies = taxonomy_vocabulary_get_names();
    foreach ($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
      $terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vocabulary);
      $term_data = [];
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_data['select'] = [
          'tid' => $term->tid,
          'name' => $term->name,
          'vid' => $term->vid,
        ];
        $select['vid'] = $term_data['select']['name'];
        $form[$vocabulary] = [
          '#title' => $vocabulary,
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#options' => [
            $select
          ]
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: More of a PHP issue than a Drupal one: you're overwriting the same form element inside the foreach loop, instead of building up an array. (`$options[] =` or `$options[$term->vid] = `), and creating one `$form` select element *after* the foreach loop.

Comment: Near same problem with 

      foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $form[$term->vid] = [
          '#title' => $term->vid,
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#options' => [
            $term->tid => $term->name
          ]
        ];
      }

Comment: This is solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924477/drupal-form-option-populate-from-loop